# Trying to build angular4 old project with webpack but failing

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, maven-2, node-modules

I am totally new in angular and getting a lot of errors during building an old angular project. Using old node version to be compatible.
version :

```
    @angular/compiler : 4
    webpack : 1.x
    awesome-typescript-loader : 3.x
    node-version - 6
```

warning starts with :

```
    "can't find source file main.ts : Error : can't resolve file or directory ./main.ts in ~\ag-grid-angular"
     follows with almost same 1000 errors
    "ERROR in [at-loader] node_moduler\@types\lodash\common\array.d.ts 23:10"
     ';' expected (repeats 1000 times same error with ';', ',', '(' combinations. Looked the code at 
      that line but found nothing wrong)
```

...

during maven build got :

```
    Error in bail mode : [at-loader] node-moduler/.../array.d.ts
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! build.prod : 'webpack .. --bail'
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

I tried with different webpack version, ts-loader instead of awesome-typescript-loader. In ts-loader the errors more decrypted. Should I move to angular-cli first or building with webpack possible?

Comment: You absolutely can build with webpack. However, webpack 1.x is going to make it very difficult. Use the latest webpack

Comment: "ERROR in [at-loader] node_moduler\@types\lodash\common\array.d.ts 23:10"
     ';' expected" how can I fix this repeatative, meaningless error?